# Splice or remove specific element in an Array

Tags: javascript

I have a variable of array like this:

```
dateArray =  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
```

Now I wanted to remove the first 12 elements of the `dateArray`. I tried the code below but it's not working still. I used `splice` but I don't know what I'm missing.

```
if(dateArray.length>12){
    for(var d= 0; d <12; d++){
       dateArray.splice(d);
    }
    console.log(dateArray);
}
```

It outputs empty array: `[]`

what I wanted it to remove only the first 12 and the output should be:

```
[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a for loop to do this

```
for(var d= 0; d <12; d++){
   dateArray.splice(d);
}
```

Could be

```
dateArray.splice(0, 12);
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Use splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
dateArray =  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

dateArray.splice(0,12);
   document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dateArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just make a new array with the values you want.

```
dateArray =  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

dateArray2 = [];

if(dateArray.length>12){
    for(var i= 0; i < 12; i++){
       dateArray2[i] = dateArray[i];
    }
    console.log(dateArray);
    console.log(dateArray2);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hq2h8wz/) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function to remove array elements.

**slice()**: The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

```
var d2 = dateArray.slice(12, dateArray.length);
console.log(d2); // [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Comment: Or `.slice(12)` - no need to specify the end element if you want everything to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try, this code

```
if(dateArray.length>12){
    dateArray.splice(0, 12);
    console.log(dateArray);
}
```

source - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
dateArray = dateArray.slice(0,12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `datearray.splice(0, 12)`. 0 = starting index, 12 = number of elements to remove.
 ref: [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the 12 elements at one time, you're not using [`splice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) the correct way, here the correct way to use it:

```
console.log(dateArraysplice(0, 12););
```

If you want to remove the first element of an array at a time, use the [`shift()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) method instead.

```
if(dateArray.length>12){
    for(var d= 0; d <12; d++){
       dateArray.shift();
    }
    console.log(dateArray);
}
```

Both method get you this output

> [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]